# How to import data to vitess

Tags: vitess

I'm new in Vitess. I've exported my database from MySQL Workbench to file mydatabase.sql. I've already downloaded docker and vitess, but now I'm trying to import those file into vitess and i don't know how to do it?

I was trying to import the database like it is written in vitess documentation

Error:

> ./lvtctl.sh ApplySchema -- --sql "$(cat tables/test_test_test.sql)" test2_keyspace
> W0607 08:54:30.334135      25 log.go:39] Failed to read in config : Config File "vtconfig" Not Found in "[/]". This is optional, and can be ignored if you are not using config files. For a detailed explanation, see https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/blob/main/doc/viper/viper.md#config-files.
> E0607 08:54:30.341838      25 main.go:96] E0607 08:54:30.341548 vtctl.go:2912] unable to get shard names for keyspace: test2_keyspace, error: node doesn't exist: vitess/global/keyspaces/test2_keyspace/shards/
> ApplySchema Error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unable to get shard names for keyspace: test2_keyspace, error: node doesn't exist: vitess/global/keyspaces/test2_keyspace/shards/
> E0607 08:54:30.342262      25 main.go:105] remote error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unable to get shard names for keyspace: test2_keyspace, error: node doesn't exist: vitess/global/keyspaces/test2_keyspace/shards/

Comment: What does the documentation say? what format should the files be in? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/tree/main/examples/compose  I stopped at the instruction load the schema

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Comment: Add detail of errors to your original question.

Comment: Maybe there is more simple way to load my file into vitess?